# Offline map-based survey app for iOS?

Tags: ios, offline, maps, land-surveying

I a looking for an iOS app or any approach, that will allow me to do offline map-based surveys and upload the data back to one single database once I am online (like the Esri Collector), but:

1. In Collector, once I finish one respondent, the second respondent
   sees the answers, I want to start with blank map.
2. I will have about 30 people with iPads in the field, I do not want them to see all the answers in one map
3. I don't have a budget to buy an app

Any ideas?

I can of course take for each respondent a new map, but then I would end up with 700 maps/shapefiles I would have to merge afterwards, what is not user friendly - so I need something like Qfield (QGIS plugin) that would work at iPads.

Comment: Ok, I found the "solution", although it is not superb, it works. I set up layers to be 100% transparent, it means, that users can see layer while creating it, but then it becomes invisible and another user on same iPad wont see previous answers. Works well for me right now.